# Receiving "SPClaimProvider.FillResolve(): Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" every few minutes

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint Server 2019 environment running on-premise. Every few minutes we're receiving the following error:

- **Log Name:** Application
- **Source:** SharePoint Foundation
- **Event ID:** 8307
- **Level:** Error

Message:

```
An exception occurred in AD claim provider when calling SPClaimProvider.FillResolve(): Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent..
```

The error does not appear to be linked to any particular action. It's been a longstanding issue in a farm we inherited, so we don't know when this first occurred. And, there has been no recent changes in the environment.

Any ideas on how we can get rid of this error?